# Automated Footer information

Tags: theme-development, themes, title, wp-title

Working on a theme and I'd like the copyright and title texts on the footer to be automated. It works but the tittle switches to the current page instead of the website's main title when you switch pages. How do I get it to stick to the website's main title or home page title.

My line of code is as shown below.

```
 &copy;<?php echo date("Y"); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_title` is always the title of the current post. What you probably want is something like `wp_title` or `get_bloginfo` and `bloginfo('name');`. Take a look at your headers code to see exactly what your theme uses

Comment: I think you can just use `get_bloginfo();` to return the a site title by default.

Comment: Use `get_bloginfo('name')` to return blogname

Answer (score 1):

Just for info, here is another function you can use to display copyright info

```
function wpse_copyright_in_footer() {
         $all_posts = get_posts('post_status=publish&order=ASC');
        $first_post = $all_posts[0];
        $first_date = $first_post->post_date_gmt;

        _e('Copyright &copy; ');
        if ( substr($first_date,0,4) == date('Y') ) {
          echo date('Y');
        } else {
          echo substr($first_date,0,4) . "-" . date('Y');
        }
        echo ' <strong>' . get_bloginfo('name') . '</strong> ';

    }
```

You can then just simply call it like this in your footer.php

```
<?php echo wpse_copyright_in_footer(); ?>
```